# How to check page content after button click correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I want to check if there loads correct page after clicking 'sign in' button.

**users_spec.rb**

```
before :each do
  user = User.create(:email => 'admin@cm.com', :password => '123')
end

it "signs me in" do
  visit '/users/sign_in'
  within("#new_user") do
    fill_in 'Email', :with => 'admin@cm.com'
    fill_in 'Password', :with => '123'
    click_button 'Sign in'
  end
  expect(page).to have_content '#{user.name}' 
end
```

expect(page).to have_content 'Dashboard' checks is there user.name word on the same page, where the form is located. So, what's the sense in click_button then? How to make it check content on the page that should load AFTER click_button? By the way, how to correctly name such tests?
Sorry, if it's a silly question, I'm a newbie in rspec :c

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pick some content that appears on the page after the user logs in.  Does your app display a message saying something like "You are now logged in", if so you can do

```
expect(page).to have_content("You are now logged in")
```

If not, does it display the users name in a header bar?  Then you can do something like

expect(page).to have_css("header", text: user.name)

etc... The key is that whatever you're searching for needs to appear on the next page but not on the page with the form. In both of those cases Capybara will wait up to `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` seconds while retrying to find the text (assuming you're using a driver other than rack-test) which should give the next page time to load.  If you're using the rack-test driver then there is no JS or asynchronous support, the click_button should have submitted a form and the expect won't execute until the next page has loaded.

As for test naming -- name it something that makes sense to you so you know what its doing a year from now.

Comment: tests do not pass if i write expect(page).to have_content("You are now logged in") even if there is dusc a message. But tests pass only if I check smth from the content where the sign_in form is located. It's not necessarily about user.name. If there is 'Hello' on the page after signing in,  expect(page).to have_content("Hello") doesn't pass if there is no this word on the page where sign_in form is located. That's the problem, i don't understand why to use button_click then, if tests don't work on the page this button refers to or am i doing smth wrong(

Comment: You are doing something wrong -- Either the app isn't actually logging in when you click the button, or you're not checking for text that exists on the next page - Your test log should show you the actual requests made.  Since you're new to rspec and capybara I assume you're using the rack-test driver, which has no JS support - does your app actually login if JS is disabled or does it require JS to work -- if so you'll need to use one of Capybaras other drivers